# std::cin directly to a function

Tags: c++

Recently I came across the following part of code. I don't know if it makes any sense, I'm just trying to understand it:

```
#include <iostream>
class foo{
    private:
        int memeber;
    public:
        int &method(){ return memeber; }
};

int main(){
    foo bar;
    std::cin >> bar.method();
}
```

I have never seen such thing before. I'm surprised that it even compiles. How can you cin directly to a function address? Can someone elaborate on what it does and if it can be used for anything?

Comment: `bar.method()` is not a function address but the reference returned from the function.

Comment: Oh, so it means that the std::cin is going to write directly to the private member of this class? Is it a good or a bad practice?

Comment: @user3125731 It's probably more bad practice to allow direct access to any private class members. But well, there might be valid use cases.

Comment: Yet another example of why aligning your asterisks and ampersands to the left is clearer: `int& method() { return memeber; }`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit problem is when you align it to the left in declaration makes it worse

Comment: @Slava: Only if you're doing silly declarations. So simply don't do that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
std::cin >> bar.method();
```

could be rewritten more verbose:

```
int &ref = bar.method();
std::cin >> ref;
```

so result of calling `method()` which is reference to `int` is passed to `std::cin.operator>>()`

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone elaborate on what it does and if it can be used for anything?

`bar.method()` returns a reference to `foo::memeber` which can be used as an lvalue.

> How can you cin directly to a function address?

It's not a *function address*.

> ```
> int &method(){ return memeber; }
>  // ^
> ```

As @Lightness [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920112/stdcin-directly-to-a-function/36920234#comment61402248_36920112) it's a bit confusing. The better (more clear) style to write that is probably

```
int& method(){ return memeber; }
// ^ makes it more clear that it's a int reference and not address of the function
```

---

The lvalue can be used with the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,T&)` operator as any other lvalue (i.e. variable).